# How to run Bootstrap css components in Heroku python Dash application

Tags: python, css, heroku, deployment, plotly-dash

I am trying to run a python Dash application in Heroku. Although i have added the right folder structure;

- app

  - app1.py
  - assets.css
  - reset.css
  - Procfile
  - .gitignore

But the Dash bootstrap components are working in Heroku environment, however the same set up working fine in my dev environment.
These are the libraries i did import

```
import dash
import os
import dash_daq as daq
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
```

Comment: `python app1.py`  at the path of folder in terminal. More info [visit](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-embed-bootstrap-css-js-in-your-python-dash-app-8d95fc9e599e) or **[read docs](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/quickstart/)**

Comment: @Rayees, css components are not working in Heroku

Comment: is not working in after deploying ?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/52481947.html

Comment: is any error showing in console?

Comment: No errors reflecting. only thing the styles and background image not reflecting in Heroku. Also, tried following the link..not sure what is the resolution in this case

Comment: got the resolution: dash.Dash(__name__). Thanks @Rayees AC

Answer (score 0):

Yes a simple trick did the way; `add __name__`

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
```

[This link provides more detailed explanation](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-app-does-not-load-assets-and-app-index-string/12178/2)